How can I make test runner respect newlines?
#include <stdio.h>

#define fixedPrice 800
#define insurance 200
#define packing 300
#define maxFreeDistance 30
#define discount 0.1
#define perFloor 75
#define costPerExtra10Km 50

int main() {
    int floors, age, distance;
    char elevator, needPacking, fragileItems;
    double totalCost = 0.0;

    /* getting input from the user + validating input  */

    printf("Enter the floor number of your apartment: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &floors);
    if (floors < 0) {
        printf("Value should be positive! ");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Is there an elevator? (y/n): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &elevator);
    if (elevator != 'y' && elevator != 'n') {
        printf("Input Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Do you need packing service? (y/n): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &needPacking);
    if (needPacking != 'y' && needPacking != 'n') {
        printf("Input Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Do you have fragile items that require insurance? (y/n): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &fragileItems);
    if (fragileItems != 'y' && fragileItems != 'n') {
        printf("Input Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age < 0) {
        printf("Value should be positive!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the distance of the move in kilometers: \n");
    scanf("%d", &distance);
    if (distance <= 0) {
        printf("Error Input!");
        return 1;
    }

    totalCost = fixedPrice;

    /* if the user has no elevator then we charge him 75 per floor starting from floors above 1 */


    if (elevator != 'y') {
        if (floors > 1)
            totalCost += (floors - 1) * perFloor;
    }

    /* if the user wants packing then we charge him for the packing service */

    if (needPacking == 'y')
        totalCost += packing;

    /*if the user got fragile items then charge for  insurance */


    if (fragileItems == 'y')
        totalCost += insurance;

    /* if the user distance is above maxFreeDistance then charge costPerExtra10km per 10 extra kms above it */


    if (distance > maxFreeDistance)
        totalCost += ((distance - maxFreeDistance) / 10) * costPerExtra10Km;

        /* if user age is above 65 then give him a discount */

    if (age >= 65)
        totalCost *= (1 - discount);

         /* we return the total cost of the move*/

    printf("The total cost of your move is: %.2f", totalCost);

    return 0;
}

I am trying to take input in same line as printf but if I remove the \n in each printf it would work in Xcode output, but then when i test run in a test runner it all prints in the same line, I don't know what else I can do to try and fix it. How can I make test runner respect the newlines the way Xcode does?
Here is the Xcode output:
Enter the floor number of your apartment: 4
Is there an elevator? (y/n): n
Do you need packing service? (y/n): y
Do you have fragile items that require insurance? (y/n): y
Enter your age: 70
Enter the distance of the move in kilometers: 50
The total cost of your move is: 1462.50

This is the test runner output:
Enter the floor number of your apartment: Is there an elevator? (y/n): Do you need packing service? (y/n): Do you have fragile items that require insurance? (y/n): Enter your age: Enter the distance of the move in kilometers: The total cost of your move is: 1462.50 .


Why would you print the prompts for an automated interaction?

printf("age? "); fflush(stdout); scanf(...);

That's normal and expected. Your output doesn't contain any newlines, so you don't see them in the testRunner output. The newlines that you see in xcode do not come from the output, but from your input (pressing Enter). Since testRunner  doesn't show the input, there are no newlines. You need to decide whether you want newlines in your output or not.

Try moving the \n from the end to the beginning of the prompt string.
In your code there are two types of data prompted for. You can use a function to handle each type of input validation to make the behaviour consistent and the main function cleaner.
#include <stdio.h>

int validatePositiveIntInput(const char *prompt) {
    int value;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &value);
    if (value < 0) {
        printf("Error: Value should be positive!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return value;
}

char validateYNInput(const char *prompt) {
    char value;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf("%c", &value);
    if (value != 'y' && value != 'n') {
        printf("Error: Please enter 'y' or 'n'.\n");
        return '\0';
    }
    return value;
}

int main() {
    int floorNumber = validatePositiveIntInput("\nEnter the floor number of your apartment: ");
    if (floorNumber < 0)
        return 1;

    char elevator = validateYNInput("\nIs there an elevator? (y/n): ");
    if (elevator == '\0')
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

